# spring security session - use in application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I understand that the spring security is creating a new session. In my case this is persistent to Gemfire. when the user logins the application is checking if a session exists if so, puts the authentication success in a session attribute. Also, a new session is created after successful login.

The issue here is, after login (spring security here), a new session cookie is created by the application (not spring security framework) and given back as session cookie value and hence when I click on any of the home page link (protected with /*) the session cookie value is checked for any authentication token in the new session. Since, this was not initially persisted the user is redirected to login page.

The issue IMO is that the application should share the session create by the spring security framework and should not create a new one at the application end.

what is the possible root cause and fix of this? help really appreciated .. Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what session cookie is created by the application? 
Why you check it each request if SpringSecurity handle authentication?

Comment: I think Java Servlet standards calls for generating a new JSESSIONID (or whatever you are using as your session attribute name) when a JSESSIONID is passed in that the application server doesn't know about.  We recently saw this behavior when an unrelated application was setting their cookie domain to *.com, basically overwritting our JSESSIONID with theirs.  My gut feeling is that your application is generating a new JSESSIONID because the one being passed in is not in cache (Gemfire).